# Symfony 2 event listener - on authentication fail / firewall listener

Tags: php, symfony

So I can perform a simple request listener:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

        //etc.
```

And in services.yml:

```
  listener.my_request_listener:
    arguments: 
      - "@translator"
    class: MyBundle\EventListener\RequestListener
    tags: 
      - 
        event: kernel.request
        method: onKernelRequest
        name: kernel.event_listener
      - 
        event: kernel.response
        method: onKernelResponse
        name: kernel.event_listener
```

What I want to do now is detect if authentication has failed (using Symfony2's in-built security component). I have all the security setup, but I need to detect when security fails. Something like this:

```
public function onKernelAuthFail(GetAuthenticationFailEvent $event) {

    //authentication failed, so action can be performed here before it redirects

}
```

I've seen this: http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ListenerInterface.html and talk of 'firewall' listeners, but I just can't understand how to do it. I bet it's only a line of code or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler` class. It should be under `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication`. This is the default listener that Symfony uses when authentication fails.

But you can write your own and use it by adding it to your `security.yml` like this:

```
firewalls:
    firewall_name:
        form_login:
            failure_handler: your.service.id
```

Here's a complete reference to the security.yml configuration:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

Comment: So when I do this, am I extending the original class or writing a  complete new one? Extension seems better.

Comment: I think they're better in this case :)

Comment: I'm still trying to get this working, and am very close with the answer posted here, but if you can help with the final thing that would be great: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515391/symfony2-trying-to-set-up-a-service-to-extend-a-class/17516309#17516309