# Symfony2 - trying to set up a service to extend a class

Tags: php, symfony

I want to extend the DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler in Symfony2.

I don't want to replace it, just extend it.

I basically want to hook in on the failure handler so if a condition is met instead of redirecting as the failure handler does, I can perform a different action.

I'm thinking I need to do this as a service.

I have this in services.yml

```
extend.auth.fail:
    class: MyBundle\Bundle\AuthenticationFailure
```

In security.yml:

```
security:

    firewalls:

        secure_area:
            pattern: ^/admin
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                failure_handler: extend.auth.fail
```

In AuthenticationFailure.php

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication;

class AuthenticationFailure extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler
{

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {

        //do something here instead

    }

}
```

...but I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailure::onAuthenticationFailure() must be compatible with that of Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface::onAuthenticationFailure() in /var/symfony/src/MyBundle/Bundle/AuthenticationFailure.php line 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### wrong namespace

namespace `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication` should be `MyBundle\Bundle` in your extending class.

### missing use statements

make sure you have the use statements for Request and AuthenticationException in your extending class.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
```

Otherwise php will look for non-existant and none-compatible classes `MyBundle\Bundle\Request` and `MyBundle\Bundle\AuthenticationException`.

Comment: Thanks. I also added a use statement for Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler. I then found I needed to pass in the two arguments in services.yml - I have passed in @service_container for both because whilst I know this is bad practice, I thought that made everything work (and I can improve after I see it working). Please see next comment...

Comment: However, I get this error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface, instance of appDevDebugProjectContainer given... I've tried @request, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: you can't just pass @request or @service_container without overriding/adapting the `__construct` method in your extending class. adapt it and it will work - the base class constructor can be found at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.php#L46